# Figuring out Insert function parameter for linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

My teacher gave the class for a driver to complete a program, and I'm unsure how to code the insert function because of it.

The line giving me trouble:

```
you.Insert(me,0);
```

`you` is for the default constructor and `me` is for an explicit value constructor, so this line is supposed create a node in `you` with the contents of `me`.

I'm lost understanding how to write the parameter to access me for my insert function

```
void WRD::Insert( ?, int new_data)
```

I'll include the explicit constructor I have, any insight understanding this mentally will help. (included example of what `insert` should look like or do based on an example I was given.)

```
WRD::WRD(const string & s)
{
    cout<<"one called\n";
    front = 0;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        AddChar(s[i]);
    }
}


class node
{
public:
    char symbol;  
    node *   next; 
};
```

v

```
oid Insert(node * &ptr, int new_data)
{
    node *new_ptr = new node;

    new_ptr -> data = new_data;
    new_ptr -> next = 0;  //always initialize a pointer

    if (Empty(ptr))
    {
        ptr = new_ptr;
    }
    else if (new_ptr->data <= ptr->data)
    {
        new_ptr->next = ptr;
        ptr = new_ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        node *fwd_ptr=ptr, *pre_ptr=ptr;

        while(fwd_ptr!=0 && (fwd_ptr->data < new_ptr->data))
        {
            pre_ptr = fwd_ptr;
            fwd_ptr = fwd_ptr->next;
        }

        if (fwd_ptr == 0)
        {
            pre_ptr->next = new_ptr;
        }
        else
        {
            new_ptr->next = fwd_ptr;
            pre_ptr->next = new_ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `you` is not a constructor. It is an object. `insert` is a method that the object has. (on assumes). Perhaps it is time to stop staring at the computer monitor and review your notes

Comment: I didn't say you was a constructor, I said it was for the constructor.

Comment: I quote '"you" is for the default constructor' I assumed you meant "you" as the name.

Answer (score 0):

Like this I think (assuming I've understood you right)

```
void WRD::Insert(const WRD& w, int new_data)
```

It might help to show more of your driver program, in particular how `you` and `me` are declared.

Comment: WRD you;     WRD me("123aabc102");

Comment: @John - " how you and me are declared" - Confused?

Comment: What is `AddChar`? What is `insert`?

Comment: @jimcolin That's what I thought, then my declaration should work I think. Not completely certain what Insert is supposed to do mind you.

Comment: @EdHeal Looks to me that WRD is a linked list of chars, and Insert is supposed to insert one WRD at a given location within another.

Comment: insert is supposed to insert a value into a node

Comment: @jimcolin Well now you have lost me.

Comment: addChar has char symbol as a parameter and creates a node with contents of function call for me.

Comment: @jimcolin Making even less sense now. I don't think you've explained the assignment very well. Perhaps because you don't understand it too well yourself.

Comment: @john - Lost me as well - Insert an int? perhaps a linked list of characters (why?). What does `Empty` do? Comparing integers and characters? .... I always believe that code should have a narrative.

Comment: Insert: Inserts  a copy of word  B (adds alphanumeric symbols that makeup B's linked list to A's linked list) into word A before position p; remember A is the current object; If p is 0, B is inserted at the front of A. If p is greater than or equal to the length of A, then B is inserted at the end of A.

Comment: @jimcolin That is **exactly** what I thought Insert should do. But how that relates to what you said about nodes and values, or how it relates to the code you have posted I still don't understand. Still it does mean that my answer above is correct.

Comment: That's from the assignment if that doesn't help nothing will, didn't want to put it. It's too much to read.

Comment: @jimcolin. Getting more confusing by the minute - Where is `A` and `B` in the code (or mentioned in the question for that matter)

Comment: @EdHeal Obviously it's describing `A.Insert(B, p);`

Comment: A would be the Default constructor having "you" as the object, B would the explicit constructor "me" as the object

Comment: @john - You are more psychic than me.